# How to make nvidia as default VGA in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have already installed the nvidia drivers and prime.
However, even though i have already `prime-select nvidia` , it doesn't show up in `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'`

[image]

How do i make my system use nvidia for display?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo prime-select query` ?

Comment: I have this problem too , what did you do to fix this issue? Did you find it?